# Get index of dynamic accordion jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-accordion

I can generate a list of accordions after an AJAX call in this way:

```
data.items.forEach(function(item,index) {
                if(item.desciption != "") {
                    $('#accordionList').append(
                        templateAccordion(item, index)
                );
          }
});
```

where templateAccordion is:

```
var templateAccordion = function(item, index) {
        return '<div class="card">' +
        '<div class="card-header" id="heading_'+index+'" data-toggle="collapse" onclick="test('+index+')" data-target="#collapse_'+index+'" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse_'+index+'">' +
        '<h5 class="mb-0">'+
          '<button class="btn btn-link collapsed">'+
            item.desciption + 
          '</button>'+
        '</h5>'+
      '</div>'+ 
      '<div id="collapse_'+index+'" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_'+index+'" data-parent="#accordionList">'+
        '<div class="card-body">' +

        '</div>'+
      '</div>'+
    '</div>'
    }
```

Problem:

I need to call another service when I click over the header of each accordion to get other data about that element. To do this, I thought 2 possible ways.

The first one is the `onclick=""` function on the header of the element (like in my example). But this solution doesn't work because I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined` (and the function exists in my javascript).

The second is trigger the click function using the `id` of the header. But it's dynamic as you can see. So I don't have it because it could be 1,2,3 and so on.

I can't loop over the whole list and try to get the correct `id`. It is unthinkable.

Is there any onther way? Maybe just understand why it gets me `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`?

Comment: Why not use a delegated event handler? Then you can simply read the `data` attributes of the clicked header and traverse the DOM to find related elements if required.

Comment: I don't really get it I'm sorry. can you please show me an example or how can i do it using a delegated event handler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Ok, as Andy wrote your solution works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#accordionList').on('click','.card-header', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works well. Thank you